# How secure IIS run together with XAMPP?

Tags: webserver, iis, xampp

I'm using IIS for web server & run phpMyAdmin via IIS.

But now, I saw someone use IIS and XAMPP. There is something I wanted to know.

```
Usually they set : XAMPP to localhost:81 or localhost:whatever
```

Something that I wanted to know is the phpMyAdmin run inside IIS is more secured than run phpMyAdmin via IIS ?

So, which one is better ?

```
1. Using IIS to run webserver (PHP) and phpMyAdmin
2. Using XAMPP inside IIS, then run webserver (PHP) using IIS and phpMyAdmin using XAMPP
```

There is something I know, I cannot directly access to phpMyAdmin if run on `localhost:81`, if I need to access phpMyAdmin I should open my server. But  I ever got hacked when I'm using XAMPP  to run PHP and phpMyAdmin.

Was looking to so many site for the answer, but still don't get the answer.

Comment: Useful post: https://serverfault.com/questions/316516/does-changing-default-port-number-actually-increase-security

Comment: hello, thank you @jrtapsell for giving me that post. But, I still dont get the answer for how secure if XAMPP run inside IIS.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are describing?

Comment: I was edited the question @jrtapsell, sorry if the question make you confused.

Comment: To confirm, you want the differences between running PMA on IIS vs proxying to XAMPP?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I wanted to know what the main differences and how about the security. @jrtapsell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Effectively you do not ever want administrative consoles, administrative applications, or insecure applications exposed to untrusted networks such as the Internet.**

It is possible to run these web-apps on other internal ports or simply ports that are not accessible to the outside world or other untrusted networks, then access the web-apps via a VPN. This would allow you to VPN to your server to do web-based configuration tasks and/or use the untrusted apps without exposing them to the Internet or untrusted networks.

**The concern is that in some cases when you add such web-based administration tools these can be exposed to both the external (untrusted) and internal (trusted) networks at the same time**, especially if it's via the same server daemon. So you will want to do a test to confirm this is not the case.

Alternatively, what some people do is **run two different webservers** on the same system (For example you could run IIS for external apps on ports 80 and 443, then run Apache with another app on a high port such as 32443 which is either blocked by a firewall or run on an internal loopback address such as 127.0.0.1. There are many ways to do this.

Back to your question of relative risk. **The system with more code/applications accessible to the untrusted networks will be at greater risk from the untrusted networks.** If you are comparing two applications side by side it will be a relative comparison at a given point in time taking into account the security controls in place for each application at it's most current version level.

In a direct comparison of the following two:

```
1.) ISS + PHP + phpMyAdmin  
2.) ISS + PHP + phpMyAdmin + XAMPP
```

**One would expect the second combination to be likely to have more vulnerabilities at a given point in time because it effectively exposes more attack surface.** There are exceptions where added software adds additional security controls but in general this is an easy way to look at your exposed attack surface.

Note: **There are many other ways to solve the problem** you are trying to solve. You could also look at using tools like [mod_security](https://www.modsecurity.org/) and the use of static IP's with firewall configurations too.

Finally, I have to point out that no matter which way you go **you will want to do a lot more to secure this system** if it is exposed to the Internet.